# Strange, intermittently consistent chirping/creaking noise from wooden pallet(s)

Tags: wooden-furniture, noise

I recently acquired 4 wooden pallets to make my couch out of. I sanded them down slightly and at that point they seemed fairly dry and in good condition to me. To be noted, they had been sitting outside for a while, in all kinds of weather conditions, including occasional rain, but as stated, at the moment of transporting them they were visibly and to the touch bone dry.

In the beginning everything was fine, but after about 3 weeks in the apartment I started hearing a strange, quiet chirping/creaking sound. It continues for a couple seconds, then pauses for a bit, then starts up again. Sometimes the pauses stretch for longer, especially if I move around or some other louder noise happens, but after a minute of quiet/consistent noise from my side (netflix show playing etc) it starts right up again. Somehow it reminds me a bit of the quiet sound a cat makes when licking itself (I have two cats, so I'm used to hearing their sounds). Also, the cats do not seem to be interested whatsoever in the sound.

I narrowed it down to the pallets, but I am still confused as to what it could be. It's not a Death Watch Beetle/woodworm, I compared the sounds and they are definitely not the same.

I did manage to record the sound with my phone. I'll include the link to the SoundCloud upload here: https://soundcloud.com/triin-michelson/chirping-m4a?ref=clipboard&p=a&c=1&si=a8376b6adbf5476eb82cd955a3b5d722

I am able to hear it pretty well when I put my phone right next to my ear, but perhaps some of you have a better audio system so you can enhance it even more. In any case I hope you'll be able to hear it.

Is it just normal wood creaking (very strangely consistent), have I gone crazy, or is it some type of a more nefarious organic issue that I should address asap?

Comment: What kind of woodworm treatment or varnish did you use?

Comment: We have a wooden floor in one room that makes a noise like a puppy yelping when you walk over it at one place. We pretend that 'Floor Pup' lives down there. He is more vocal in damp weather.

Comment: I haven't used any treatments on the pallets as of yet. They need some more sanding and then I was going to go over them with simple dark wood stain. The cardboard clicking noise comment unfortunately does not answer my question as the sound they described is different.